# How to generate a dummy treatment variable based on values from two different variables

Tags: r, filtering, data-manipulation, dummy-variable

I would like to generate a dummy treatment variable "treatment" based on country variable "iso" and earthquakes dummy variable "quake" (for dataset "data").

I would basically like to get a dummy variable "treatment" where, if quake==1 for at least one time in my entire timeframe (let's say 2000-2018), I would like all values for that "iso" have "treatment"==1, for all other countries "iso"==0. So countries that are affected by earthquakes have all observations 1, others 0.

I have tried using dplyr but since I'm still very green at R, it has taken me multiple tries and I haven't found a solution yet. I've looked on this website and google.

I suspect the solution should be something along the lines of but I can't finish it myself:

```
data %>%
filter(quake==1) %>%
group_by(iso) %>%
mutate(treatment)
```

Comment: you could use `data %>%
  group_by(iso) %>%
  mutate(treatment = as.integer(any(quake == 1)))` and if you have only 1/0 values in `quake`, `data %>%
  group_by(iso) %>%
  mutate(treatment = as.integer(any(quake)))` should work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow ! You should really consider Sotos's links for your next questions on SO :)
Here is a `dplyr` solution (following what you started) :

```
## data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(year = rep(2000:2002, each = 26), 
                   iso = rep(LETTERS, times = 3),
                   quake = sample(0:1, 26*3, replace = T))
## solution (dplyr option)
library(dplyr)
data2 <- data %>% arrange(iso) %>%
        group_by(iso) %>%
        mutate(treatment = if_else(sum(quake) == 0, 0, 1))
data2 
# A tibble: 78 x 4
# Groups:   iso [26]
    year iso   quake treatment
   <int> <fct> <int>     <dbl>
 1  2000 A         0         1
 2  2001 A         1         1
 3  2002 A         1         1
 4  2000 B         1         1
 5  2001 B         1         1
 6  2002 B         0         1
 7  2000 C         0         1
 8  2001 C         0         1
 9  2002 C         1         1
10  2000 D         1         1
# ... with 68 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ANG, Ronak Shahs and Sotos for the quick responses! All of the different responses seemed to work well. I'll keep an eye on how to pose better questions next time, thanks!